# Google Chrome doesn't import Keychain credidentials after update

Tags: google-chrome, keychain

I had installed the new Google Chrome update and after I restarted the browser, it stopped using my Keychain credentials. Is  it possible to solve this problem somehow ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, after restarting Chrome two times the issue resolved itself.